# Python: Pass string into function with re

Tags: python, function

I am new to Python. I created the below function to search a text using regex in a file. The result is then written to an excel sheet.

But I get  the error "NonType" object has no attribute group for  (which mean match is not found).

```
b_list=re.split('\s+', str(b.group()))
```

However, when I use the function as normal code, I am able to find the text. So it means the passed values into the function didn't work.

How do I pass strings or variables correctly into the function? Thank you.

The complete code as below.

```
import re
import openpyxl


def eval_text(mh, search_text, excel_sht, excel_col):
b_regex=re.compile(r'(?<=mh ).+')
b=b_regex.search(search_text)
b_list=re.split('\s+', str(b.group()))

if abs(b)>1:
    cell_b=excel_sht.cell(row=i, column=excel_col).value='OK'
 
else abs(b)<1:
     cell_b=excel_sht.cell(row=i, column=excel_col).value='Not OK'

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsm', data_only=True,  read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
 
sht=wb['test']
url=sht.cell(row=1, column=1).value
 
 
      with open (url, 'r') as b:
        diag_text_lines=b.readlines()
        diag_text="".join(diag_text_lines) 
        eval_text('jame', diag_text, sht, 9)
```

Comment: have you done the indentation right in function? cause it is not right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `mh` parameter is not used anywhere else in the function, I assume that you expected it to get automatically inserted in place of the `mh` in the regular expression `r'(?<=mh ).+'`. However, this does not happen! You have to use a format string, e.g. `f'(?<={mh} ).+'` (note that besides the `{...}` I replaced the "raw" `r` prefix, which you do not really need here, with `f`).

```
def eval_text(mh, search_text, excel_sht, excel_col):
    b_regex=re.compile(f'(?<={mh} ).+')
    b = b_regex.search(search_text)
    ...
```

For older versions of Python, use the `format` method instead. If there are more `{...}` used in the regex, this might not work, though. In the worst case, you can still concatenate the string yourself: `r'(?<=' + mh + r' ).+'` or use the old `%` format `r'(?<=%s ).+' % mh`.